# SK-Learn preprocessing Pipeline, garbaged output

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I built a preprocessing pipeline as below

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, num_attr),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_attr)])
```

I'm trying to fit the pipleline on my X_train. X_train is as below

```
icker       SF1            SF2            SF3              SF4              SF5 SF6
$NTAP   -0.628651934     0.98889147    -0.055714478     0.774378771   0.551088847   -1.329228593
$WYNN   1.315785931      1.438754002    0.187327182     0.608933159  -1.153029724   1.85944112
$DRI    -1.141388142    -1.455015677    0.332754543     0.674501682   0.111326137   -0.478596905
$ge     -0.054839437    -1.454148681    -0.162266534    -0.681870355  0.307868519   -0.529986948
```

I used the the below chunk to preprocess

```
clf_nm = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor)])
X_train_nm = pd.DataFrame(clf_nm.fit_transform(X_train))
```

But the "X_train_nm", the output of the above is having garbage values as below

```
0
0   (0, 0)\t0.42994752134634545\n (0, 1)\t0.569...
1   (0, 0)\t-0.47129140614423404\n (0, 1)\t0.13...
2   (0, 0)\t0.6391234497799465\n (0, 1)\t0.2931...
3   (0, 0)\t-2.0106536281536562\n (0, 1)\t-0.92...
4   (0, 0)\t0.9782971304731922\n (0, 1)\t0.6534...
... ...
18899   (0, 0)\t0.7572819165580632\n (0, 1)\t-0.354...
18900   (0, 0)\t-0.3687666927075019\n (0, 1)\t-0.88...
18901   (0, 0)\t-0.7313605840625186\n (0, 1)\t1.146...
18902   (0, 0)\t0.5782862084049006\n (0, 1)\t1.3732...
18903   (0, 0)\t0.4332583276430423\n (0, 1)\t-0.555...
18904 rows × 1 columns
```

Can someone tell me how i can fix it? Appreciate the help

Comment: Your pipeline is working fine on the data you have provided. Check the data types of your data frame features.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the purpose of `Pipeline` is that the last step should be a predictor. Here you should wrap the preprocessor in a pipeline which will have no effect. You directly call `preprocessor.fit_transform`. In your case, you should have something:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

pipe = make_pipeline(preprocessor, LogisticRegression()
y_pred = pipe.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

So in your example, `X_train` is weird because you don't have categorical features. However, you did a transformer specifically for these columns. So be aware that `X_train` should be several columns with some numerical columns and some other will be categorical.

The last point, printing the output gives weird formatting because the output of `ColumnTransformer` might be sparse (and it is in this case). If you want to see the representation as a numpy array instead, just do `print(preprocessor.fit_transform(X).A)`. Be aware that the sparse matrix will be more memory efficient if you have zeros during your preprocessing (e.g. having a OneHotEncoder).

Comment: As you rightly pointed, my output was a sparse matrix. So, converted it to a dense matrix using "todense()". this trick worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your X_train only have numerical features and you execute a transformer for categorical features.

Comment: maybe its just that the num_attr should be set? Also not sure what should happen with "icker" which I believe is "Ticker" :-)